# Nothing file in request.files

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have web project with entity framework 6.0 
I upload file with Javascript in xmlhttprequest
but in server side when I want catch the file with request.files
request.files is empty!
I upload file with dropzone,but after a time without result i try js code like below
but the probleam is same to dropzone.js

What I have tried:

javascript code:

```
var that = this;
debugger;
var url = "../../Ajax/GlobalHandler.aspx?Command=UploadImage";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fd = new FormData();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    // Every thing ok, file uploaded
        console.log(xhr.responseText); // handle response.
    }
};
fd.append("upload_file", file);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type); 
xhr.send(fd);
```

c# code:

```
Guid fileGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
string fileName = string.Empty;

foreach (string s in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFile File = Request.Files[s];

    if (File == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(File.FileName))
        continue;

    var fileContent = new byte[File.InputStream.Length];

    File.InputStream.Read(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
    File.InputStream.Close();
    File.InputStream.Dispose();

    var dot = File.FileName.LastIndexOf(".");
    var ext = string.Empty;
    if (dot >= 0)
        ext = File.FileName.Substring(dot + 1);

    fileName = fileGuid.ToString() + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ext) ? string.Empty : "." + ext);
    FileStream filestream = new FileStream(Context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data") + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);
    filestream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
    filestream.Close();
    filestream.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use jquery (or any other js library) for making `POST` requests.

Comment: I've made your code readable. Please don't post deliberately obfuscated code here.

Comment: which library? can you tell me more than this?

Comment: which Jquery library can post form data for upload?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp).

Comment: I use this code:

Comment: $.ajax({
                    url: "../../Ajax/GlobalHandler.aspx?Command=UploadImage",
                    data: data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });

Comment: that data come from:

Comment: data = new FormData();
                data.append('file',file);

Comment: but it is not work too!

Comment: I'm not sure but http request not send on time and send with delay(like it is wait to end the function and then execute) but why?

Comment: finally I find a solution, .net framework must be 4.0, but what?